# How to select correct enum value from a kotlin function

Tags: kotlin

i am expecting some string value and i need to find, if i have corresponding enum value defined.

my enum value is

```
enum class Status {
    Created, Updated
}
```

and what i want to achieve in this function is to check if any of these enum values matching, ignore the case

```
private fun getStatus(
        value: String
    ): Status {
        ....
    }
```

if nothing matched then i want to throw an error.

thank you so much for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in functions for enums like `Enum.valueOf` or `enumValueOf<Enum>` are case-sensitive, but you can easily write your own case-insensitive versions:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumValueOfIgnoreCase(key: String): T =
    enumValues<T>().find { it.name.equals(key, ignoreCase = true) }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("no value for key $key")
```

Then you can write for instance the following to obtain the `Status` element `Created`:

```
val status = enumValueOfIgnoreCase<Status>("created")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: in this answer, I missed the requirement that the function should be case-insensitive. Those built-in functions only find exact matches.

---

**Original answer:**

There is a built-in `valueOf()` function that you can use which does exactly that:

```kotlin
val status = Status.valueOf("Created")
```

If you're in a generic context and cannot use the enum class name directly, you can also use `enumValueOf()`:

```kotlin
val status = enumValueOf<Status>("Created")
```

Here is the doc about this:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants

Comment: The question is to "check if any of these enum values matching, *ignore the case*". Neither `valueOf` nor `enumValueOf` are case-insensitive. Also, it is important to note that `enumValueOf` cannot be used in just any generic context, because it is an inline function with reified type parameter.

Comment: Good catch, I missed that part in the question.